# SPARQL: Return subjects w/ more than one specific type of object

Tags: sparql, triplestore, triples, n-triples

Thanks in advance.  I have an issue where merging some work produces two guids for a single subject in my triplestore.  I need a way to isolate all of those instances so that I can normalize those guids.  I'm new to SPARQL.  I've tried returning these by COUNT and FILTER, but have so far failed.  Here's what we're looking at.

```
<http://example.com/#bar> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> 
<http://example.com/#choo> .
<http://example.com/#bar> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> 
<http://example.com/#terms> .
<http://example.com/#bar> <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#prefLabel> 
<http://example.com/#bar/bar_en> .
<http://example.com/#bar> <http://www.foo.com/#guid> "17bda3bb-7db9-4afa- 
bb95-29da6464f137" .
<http://example.com/#bar> <http://www.foo.com/#guid> "1fa33bad-a98d-4a7e- 
8679-d8777e690c0c" .
```

Sorry, that wrapped text makes this harder to read.  However, you can see here that I have a subject, http://example.com/#bar which has two guids.  I have many cases like this in the same graph and I need a way to identify them all.  Thanks again.

Comment: untested: `select ?s {?s a ?type} group by ?s having (count(?type) > 1))`

Comment: @AKSW: Perfect!  Thanks.  It took a little tweaking, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alluded to in @AKSW's comment you should be able to use `HAVING` to filter on aggregations combined with grouping by the subject to achieve this:

```
SELECT ?subject (COUNT(?guid) AS ?numGuids)
WHERE
{
  ?subject <http://www.foo.com/#guid> ?guid .
}
GROUP BY ?subject
HAVING (?numGuids > 1)
```